# Cross-referencing (input) multiple tex. files on multiple levels

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, input

I´ve recently discovered this site and you might be able to give me some advice working with LaTeX.

Here´s my problem:

My company is working on several user manuals. Each user manual is located in its own directory (repository for svn etc.).
Basically, all user manuals have the same structure: Main `.tex` file (providing all `\input`s to document class, \inputs, tables etc.) --> Chapter --> `.tex` file (optional, not always used but pretty often.) There is a lot of cross-referencing going on.

So, our structure is basically t1 -->t2-->t3. t standing for `.tex`.
Our goal is t1-->t2-->t3(-->t4).

We are trying to outsource certain phrases. E.g., the preface is basically always the same. This way, we are able to maintain various user manuals using just one `.tex` file (basically 1 `.tex` file). The problem is: We don´t want to create a directory for common phrases and texts. Our file structure depends on individual repositories/ directories. As a consequence, there is no general relative path that we can use:

A chapter in Manual 1 (t1) requires `chapter/xxx.tex` (which inputs `aaa.tex`) as an input path.
Chapters in Manual 2 and 3 require `/../../manual1/chapter/xxx.tex`.

The path used to input the `aaa.tex` file referenced in `xxx.tex` is based on the main `.tex` file (t1) from manual 1.  This path won´t work for manual 2 and 3. If I adjust the path for manual 2 and 3, the path won´t work with manual 1.

Is there any way to fix or at least "avoid" this. It would be great to reference to an additional level using a path that will work for several manuals.

I hope you don´t consider this question an annoying noob question and I´ve somehow made myself clear, but I´ve been searching for quite a while now and haven´t found an appropriate solution yet. It would be great if you could help me fix this.

Comment: Why don't you put the files you want to use with many manuals in a texmf tree so that they can be found (like e.g. article.cls) from everywhere?

Comment: In this case, I won´t thank you for your advice ;) I´ve never herad of texmf tree (I just started working with latex. Most of my epxerience is based on docbook and xml). A quick qoogle search makes me believe, that a txmf tee is not what we "want". As mentioned before, our file structure must remain untouch. Each repository is based on (if not even required by) a specific structure. So I/ we cannot change that (scripts, builds etc. depend on it)

Comment: I must confess I have difficulties following your file structure (which I understand must remain unchanged). What I understand is that there are several hierarchical levels in the folder structure which are in many respects *similar*, but (almost) never *identical*. Is that so? Maybe an actual example structure would me more enlightening.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question (and your structure). Imho it doesn't make sense to keep a common file used by many projects in a directory specific to one project. In miktex I would put such common files in a folder `mycommonfiles/tex/latex` and then register `mycommonfiles` as a new root/texmf tree.

Comment: Our file structure is basicall always the same: repositoryxyz-->documentation (main tex. file for pdf build)-->administration_manual (referenced.tex files)-->outsourced sections folder (optional). Personally, I agree that outsourcing would be the best solution. But: We cannot change our file structure since it connected to our software build-process (software engineering). Besides, we want to remain flexible (even though it might be a bit chaotic): There is a lot of cross-referencing but only a few "real" common texts. I gues its simply too much effort due to our rather stiff file structure.